# Method name expected Delegate

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a calculator with delegates and classes, but I am facing this problem when I try to refer my class to delegate it gives me an error called `"Method name expected"`

This is my delegate   `public delegate int Conculate();`

and this is where I want to execute it:

`Conculate conculate = new Conculate(action.Addition(a, b));`
but I am getting an error here `action.Addition(a, b)` showing me "Method name expected "
here's my fool program:

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 0, b = 0;
            Actions action = new Actions();
            Console.Title = "Calculator";
            bool isCountable = true;
           
            
            Dictionary<string, string> actionDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {   "+", "addition" },
                {"-", "substraction" },
                {"*","multiplication" },
                { "/", "division"}
            };

            while (isCountable)
            {

               
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your numbers");
                try
                {
                    a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The string hasn't been convented to int!!");
                    continue;
                }
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("You can only use +, -, /, *");
                Console.WriteLine("So choose a fucnion above");

                var conc = new Conculate(action);

                string execution = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
               
                    switch (execution)
                    {
                        case "+":
                            Console.WriteLine(action.Message(actionDictionary[execution]));
                            Console.WriteLine(action.Addition(a, b));
                            break;
                        case "-":
                            Console.WriteLine(action.Message(actionDictionary[execution]));
                            Console.WriteLine(action.Sub(a, b));
                            break;
                        case "*":
                            Console.WriteLine(action.Message(actionDictionary[execution]));
                            Console.WriteLine(action.Mult(a, b));
                            break;
                        case "/":
                            Console.WriteLine(action.Message(actionDictionary[execution]));
                            action.Division(a, b);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("There's no such an option");
                            break;
                    }

                
               
                isCountable = action.Answer();
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is where I try to call a delegate from another class to this class

```
public delegate int Conculate(int a, int b); 
  public class Actions
    {

        public bool Answer()
        {
            string message = "Do you want to continue?";
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            string answer = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            if (answer != "y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bye!");
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
        public int Addition(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        public int Sub(int a, int b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
        public int Mult(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
        public void Division(float a, float b)
        {
            float d;
            if (b == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("You cannot devide this number by 0");
            else
            {
                d = a / b;
                Console.WriteLine(d);
            }
        }
        public string Message(string execution, string message = "Your answer is...")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"You've chosen the {execution} option");
            return message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this all we have to go by? A `Method name expected` tends to mean that `A Method name is expected`. You've provided the pointer to the function but not the **implementation**. Make a `function int Conculate() { //with implementation here }`

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, I have 2 classes in different programs.cs in the same project but I tried to implement a delegate class in both of the mentioned programs.cs. However, the problems hadn't disappeared yet

Comment: Please show us, I'm just guessing with what you've provided, I can see the problem, I just can't give you an answer based on the information. @Mosia almost has it with `Conculate conculate = new Conculate(Addition);`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
action.Addition(a, b)
```

returns int not a function, you should create a delegate from it like this :

```
Conculate conculate = () => action.Addition(num1, num2);
```

This is working, you need to call the with parameters

```
public class ConsoleApp2
{
    public delegate int Conculate();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class2 action = new Class2();
        int num1 = 10, num2 = 20;

        Conculate conculate = () => action.Addition(num1, num2);
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int Addition(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

Comment: This already calls `action.Addition`... What if I want to use the delegate more than once with different values everything? It won't work.

Comment: So your delegate should have the parameters, like public delegate int Conculate(int, num1, int num2);

Comment: That's right! You want to be able to use any method that matches the delegate's signature...

Comment: @MosiaThabo, maybe yes but his definition of Conculate is public delegate int Conculate() so it not accepts parameters.

Comment: `() => action.Addition(num1, num2);` that creates a new function returning the result of `action.Addition(num1, num2)` which is not what you want to do with delegates... You want to pass a reference to a function. this `action.Addition(num1, num2)` calls it and doesn't pass it's reference...

Comment: Maybe to illustration my point, check the JS fiddle I provided below on my answer, it will give you an idea. Because in my case I passed a reference to `Addition` method. And then I proceeded to use the delegate instance by calling with and passing the params... ex. `conclude(a,b)` ... But with your answer, you can't pass the params...

Comment: @MosiaThabo, you are right about what you say but the question is different from this, in the question his delegate int Concula() and not delegate int Conculate(int, num1, int num2), im answering about what he asked, else i could write the whole thing in other way

Comment: LOL! He made a mistake on his description of the question. His code has this `public delegate int Conculate(int a, int b); `... But I get what you're saying. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the `delegate` is expecting a method name. In other works, you aren't supposed to pass a call of the referenced method to `delegate` contructor.

I haven't actually performed delegates and used a method that exist outside of the `class` where that `delegate` is defined. But I had just done a .NetFiddle so that I could troubleshoot your issue. So let's see how we can sort it out.

Please try do the following:

```
Conculate conculate = new Conculate(action.Addition);
```

You can even shortten this by assigning just the parameter itself:

```
Conculate conculate = action.Addition;
```

And when you call your delegate, you will then pass the params `conculate(a, b)`.

Here's a working [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oUKpHD)

---

Just make sure that `action` is an instance of a public `Actions` class.

Comment: I cannot add just a class to here "Conculate conculate = new Conculate(Addition);" because  "action"  is a class which is located in another class program.cs and addition belongs to that class that I want to call in my delegate

Comment: I have just updated my answer and provided a .NETFiddle to show you how it works. Please check it out.